# Fail safe reading s3_bucket_object with terraform when object doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to safely load data from an `s3_bucket_object`. Meaning if s3 object doesn't exist provide a default value instead. Is there a way to do that ?

If I specify the non existing key, I get a failure

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "deployed_builds_s3" {
  bucket = my_bucket_name
  key    = "path/to/file.txt"
}
```

error:

```
Error: Failed getting S3 object: NotFound: Not Found
```

I know it's possible to do with local files like this for example:

```
locals {
  file_content = fileexists("file.txt") ? file("file.txt") : ""
}
```

Is there something similar with s3 objects ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the help of [aws_s3_bucket_objects](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket_objects). Specifically, first you will call it with the object key of interest:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_objects" "my_object" {
  bucket = my_bucket_name
  prefix = "path/to/file.txt"
}
```

If the object exists, they `keys` attribute will have 1 element. Subsequently, you can **conditionally** execute `aws_s3_bucket_object` as follows:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "deployed_builds_s3" {

  count  = length(data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_object.keys)

  bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_object.keys[0]
  key    = data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_object.bucket
}
```

The about will execute if the number of keys found is greater than 0. This is enabled through [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) meta-argument.

Comment: Thanks again @Marcin! This worked, and just for others reference , to get the conditional file content my `locals` looks like this now: 
`file_content = length(data.aws_s3_bucket_object. deployed_builds_s3) == 1 ? data.aws_s3_bucket_object. deployed_builds_s3[0].body :  "" `